# Work and Study in Germany

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, study

I am going to work and live in Germany in the next month as Software Engineer.

I will have a work permit. Is it possible to study such as applying for a Bachelor's Degree or a Master's or this is not possible?

If it is not possible to study and work at the same time, what are the options of extending my Studies in Germany?

Comment: Do you want to continue working full-time and study full-time? That's going to be much harder than sorting out the legal stuff which isn't impossible. As long as you continue to fulfill the criteria for your work permit you can study as much as you like.

Comment: Work full time study part time.

Comment: Maybe FernUni Hagen could be interesting to you, the (only?) state-run distance-education university in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know precisely about Germany but typically studying is not a restricted activity for foreigners as far as the law is concerned. Therefore, a student visa is merely a visa for which you qualify by being a student and which often comes with restrictions on other activities (and in particular working, which is almost always a restricted activity).

But if you do qualify for another type of visa (work permit in your case but a spouse or family visa could work too) then you are allowed to study as well if you wish.

What might however be more difficult is finding an institution that would take part-time students and offer the courses you need with a timetable that can be reconciled with your work schedule.